# Model Fields Aren't Migrating

Tags: django

I ran into an odd error. I can't seem to get a model to hold properties anymore - its so strange.

I've got a simple GFK model:

```
class Votes(GenericFKBaseModel):

    thumbs_up = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    thumbs_down = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

I'll run `./manage.py makemigrations (with the app name)` - it shows that the model has been primed to migrate.

Then I run `./manage.py migrage` - and it shows the model being migrated successfully.

However, when I create a new Votes object and check the admin, thumbs_up and thumbs_down aren't available properties. Does anyone know why this is occurring? I've encountered this before.. :(

I should mention... both the properties in the model aren't available to hold data. If I try to write to them, I get:

```
'thumbs_up' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I can create objects without those properties, but they don't seem to even exist in the database.

Edit:

I changed the model name to Votess and ran the migration process again with the properties in the model. Again, it migrated just fine but those data members are not persisting into the database for some odd reason.

I must be missing something grand here...

Edit2:

If I add a `StringField` or an `InterField`, it works perfectly fine and as normal. But I can't add `BooleanField`s at all for some reason.

Edit3:

This seems to only be happening in SQLite.

Comment: Have you defined a ModelAdmin for Votes that restricts the fields displayed, perhaps?

Comment: Nope. I actually can't write to them either. If I try to insert a `thumb_up` or `thumb_down` , django throws the `invalid keyword argument for function` error. They aren't making it into the scheme for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

It appears to work after I removed the underscores for some strange reason.

Old:

```
thumbs_up = models.BooleanField(default = False)
thumbs_down = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

New:

```
thumbsup = models.BooleanField(default = False)
thumbsdown = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```